# How to add Docusign Recipient with Email using Conga Composer

Tags: docusign, conga, conga-composer

I'm trying to use Conga and DocuSign parameters to add an email recipient to the DocuSign envelope rather than an Id.

Here are the parameters I am using:

```
&templateid=templateId
&DocuSignR1Email=emailAddress
&DocuSignR1Name=firstname+lastname
&DocuSignR1Role=Signer+1
&DocuSignR1Type=Signer
&DS7=7
```

When I do that, it finishes in Conga and brings me to the DocuSign page, however the Recipient it created doesn't retain the email or name:

[image]

However, if I switch the email and name parameters with the Id parameter, the Recipient fills in with the correct Contact:

```
&templateid=templateId
&DocuSignR1Id=contactId
&DocuSignR1Role=Signer+1
&DocuSignR1Type=Signer
&DS7=7
```

What am I doing wrong with the email and name parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I had was that the Sandbox I was working in was using a trial version of DocuSign. It appears these features are unavailable in the trial version.

Once I tried it in a Sandbox with an active DocuSign license this worked as expected.